# How to do any command in nla using python

Tags: python, scripting

For example i can delete a mesh from 3d viewport using the code from 'info' but cannot do the same to the nla strips. Im using the code below.thanks

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.nla.delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you want to avoid using `bpy.ops` to do stuff like this. The `ops` module is usually reliant on the viewport context. So it's okay to use if you want to put it into a script that you'll assign to a hotkey to use in the nla_editor itself, but if you try to use it to affect the data directly from the script editor it will fail because it sees you aren't working in the correct viewport.

It's almost always going to be better to access the data directly like so:

```
import bpy 


c = bpy.context 
obj = c.active_object 

tracks = obj.animation_data.nla_tracks[:] 

for track in tracks:
    for strip in track.strips:
        track.strips.remove(strip)
```

If you only want to delete certain ones then you would just add some criteria like:

```
# ...

for track in tracks:
    if track.name == "Bad_Track_Name":
        for strip in track.strips:
            track.strips.remove(strip)
```

Comment: this solved it, thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries! happy blending